# Button/Drop Down open in new window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, I have a little site I made, and it has some drop down options for our company to use. I am trying to get the "Go" buttons I have created to open the links from the drop down in a new tab, that way you do not lose the page, because it currently opens the link in the same tab as the help page. I will paste a sample below, and if I can get any assistance that would be a

```
<select id="Polynesian">
  <option value="#">Choose a CMTS</option>
  <option value="http://MYURL1/">Pond</option>
  <option value="http://MYURL2/">Beach</option>
</select>
<button id="go" onclick="gotosite()">Go</button>
```

And here is my button js I created for each button.

```
function gotosite() {
  window.location = document.getElementById("GulfPlace").value; // JQuery:  $("#GulfPlace").val();
  window.location = document.getElementById("Polynesian").value; // JQuery:  $("#Polynesian").val();
  window.location = document.getElementById("GrandCaribbean").value; // JQuery:  $("#GrandCaribbean").val();
  window.location = document.getElementById("DunesOfSeagrove").value; // JQuery:  $("#DunesOfSeagrove").val();
  window.location = document.getElementById("PinnaclePort").value; // JQuery:  $("#PinnaclePort").val();
}
```

Comment: Hi! So what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: It just opens the pages in the same window, meaning you have to go back or reopen the page to get to the tools.

Comment: That actually completely broke the button, and it now opens nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.open()` with `_blank` option to open in new tab

```
 function gotosite() {
  window.open(document.getElementById("GulfPlace").value,'_blank'); // JQuery:  $("#GulfPlace").val();
  window.open(document.getElementById("Polynesian").value,'_blank'); // JQuery:  $("#Polynesian").val();
  window.open(document.getElementById("GrandCaribbean").value,'_blank'); // JQuery:  $("#GrandCaribbean").val();
  window.open(document.getElementById("DunesOfSeagrove").value,'_blank'); // JQuery:  $("#DunesOfSeagrove").val();
  window.open(document.getElementById("PinnaclePort").value,'_blank'); // JQuery:  $("#PinnaclePort").val();
}
```

Comment: You the man, that works perfectly!!! I tried this before, but maybe I was missing something simple that screwed it up!!! Thanks for the quick reply!